# Enterprise Pattern : AccountsSelector: @Override specified for non-overriding method: List<Schema.SObjectField> sptSObjectFieldList()

Tags: package, design-patterns, enterprise, fflib

We have AccountsSelector class extending ApplicationSObjectSelector abstract class from at4dx library.

- ApplicationSObjectSelector class has public virtual method getSObjectFieldList()

I have overridden that method as per source codes in selector class without an issue like [this](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/at4dx-samplecode/blob/master/sfdx-source/reference-implementation-common/main/classes/selectors/AccountsSelector.cls).

I have compiled core package with all classes from fflib librarry.
Problem is when I am trying to compile new dependant package(same namespace) which includes selector class. I am facing an issue with selectors while package compilation as follows
for e.g

```
test.AccountSelector.getSObector: @Override specified for non-overriding method: 
    List<Schema.SObjectField> 
 test.AccountsSelector.getSObjectFieldList()
```

Comment: Sonali -- it would be helpful if you used [edit] and excerpted the relevant class files and defined which class files are in which packages and how package dependencies are defined

Comment: As I explained there are only two packages core & let's say selectors . Selector is dependent on core.
AccountsSelector is part of Selectors package and  
ApplicationSObjectSelector  is aprt of Core package

Comment: There is a known issue that might me applicable here depending on the namespace of the code involved. See [The Stub API fails when used with types containing "_r" in the name or namespace and there are generics in the method signature](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001wr5UQAQ)